# How to retrieve subdocuments field value from array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I get each productID in cart from below document in mongodb.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("572992d6fc8b7a5c613248f6"),
    "userId": "0001",
    "fname": "Ankur",
    "lname": "Vishnoi",
    "address1": "Palam",
    "city": "New Delhi",
    "state": "Delhi",
    "pin": 110077,
    "cart": [
        {
            "productId": 8,
            "cartQty": 1
        }, 
        {
            "productId": 2,
            "cartQty": 3
        },
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mongo Aggregate function to $unwind the array elements. Then apply $project to get the productId.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {$unwind : "$cart"},
    {$project : { _id : 0, "productId" : "$cart.productId"}}
])
```

Result:

```
{ "productId" : 8 }
{ "productId" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should de-normalise your documents using the the[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline operator unless you have to. The best way to do this is using the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator.

```js
db.carts.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "productId": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$cart", 
                "as": "crt", 
                "in": "$$crt.productId" 
            } 
        } 
    }} 
])
```